# Why do exercises for lower back pain concentrate on the abdominal musciles?

Tags: pain, exercise, lumbago-low-back-pain

I've gone to physical therapy twice in my life for lower back pain. Each time the exercises I was given concentrated on improving the strength of the abdominal muscles, never the gluteus group of muscles, which, among other things, enable us humans to walk upright. So why don't exercises for lower back pain also include exercises to improve the strength of the gluteus group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner core is where majority of the Chronic LBP research supports working.

**Inner Core**

- Transverse Abdominis
- Multifidus
- Diaphragm
- Pelvic Floor

[image]

---

**Transverse Abdominis Dysfunction**

- Numerous studies demonstrated timing and thickness change deficits in
  subjects with LBP and athletes with groin pain
- When respiration is challenged, TrA is the first muscle recruited to
  assist with expiration
- Activation of TrA is preparatory, normally occurs before activation
  of primary mover and is not direction dependant.

---

**There's no reason you can't work your glutes** - research support this as well:

> EMG results demonstrated that subjects with chronic lower back pain had significantly
>   higher levels of recruitment for the lower and upper gluteus maximus,
>   hamstrings, and erector spinae muscles during rotation when compared
>   to the control subjects

---

**Supporting Research:**

- http://journals.lww.com/spinejournal/Abstract/2006/12150/Low_Back_Pain_Patients_Demonstrate_Increased_Hip.18.aspx
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3806175/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2899579/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3805012/
- http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0141777